# do the jquery(selector,...) overloads wait for the dom to finish loading?

Tags: dom, jquery

The `jquery(callback)` docs clearly state that it waits for the DOM to finish loading before running the function. [ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3]

The `jquery(selector, ...)` docs on the other hand, seem unclear as to whether the DOM will be finished loading by the time the selector runs.

So, and here is the real question: please can someone tell me whether I really need to nest all my selectors inside of a jquery(callback) like I am currently doing?

`jquery(function() { jquery(selector).dostuff(); })`

(or `$(function() { $(selector).dostuff(); })` which is the same)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jQuery(callback)` overload is a shorthand for `jQuery(document).ready(callback)`, so it will run the code in the callback function when the document has been parsed.

The `jQuery(selector, ...)` is not a shorthand for any event binding, it will return the elements matched by the selector at the moment that the code runs.

---

A method that doesn't use a callback is actually not able to wait until the document has been parsed. If the method would just wait for the document to be finished, that would never happen. While the Javascript code is running, the browser doesn't continue to parse the document.

Answer (score 3):

No, `jQuery(selector)` does not wait for the DOM to finish loading. `jQuery(callback)` is just a shorthand for `jQuery(document).ready(callback)`, and the `ready` event represents the DOM being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You only to wrap your code when you need the current page (in the DOM) to be available when your code runs.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the jQuery docs that the callback function wait's for the DOM to load, when you select a element you do not have a callback function.

This has a callback function.

```
jQuery(function() {

});
```

This doesn't

```
jQuery('#element');
```